# Driving 10ch outputs with 5V AVR

Tags: mosfet, avr, atmega, darlington

I use a 5V AVR (ATmega1284p) to measure some data. Depending on the data I would like to switch one of 10 outputs.
Each of these outputs should have a LED (as an indicator and for debugging purposes) and an open-drain (?) output.
The output voltage should be changable based on the users needs(max. 12V, 100mA). 10 Hz will be the fastest switching speed.

How can I do this? Should I use mosfets or rather a darlington array?
Can you please recommend devices and a schematic I could use?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want each output to be 12v when "High" and open drain when "Low", with an LED for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you actually want is a push-pull (high or low voltage) output. Usually an open drain output means an output that is either connected to a low voltage or disconnected (High impedance), used for two way communication with a single external pull-up voltage, like I2C.

You can use a circuit like this, which I've devised based on how a microcontroller pin might provide the functionality you want. Since you are switching a higher voltage than your output pin's high voltage, you need a special two-MOSFET switch, which I've labeled High side switch in the below schematic. This is somewhat analagous to the Darlington idea you suggested. The low side is just an N-MOSFET which connects the pin to ground when the output is low. You can apply your variable voltage in place of the +12 V shown. As for how to get such a variable power supply voltage, somebody else will have to chime in as I'm not sure of the best way.

[image: Driver circuit]

You can see this circuit simulated using [this applet](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKABkRC88QAWOChkJ8BVKgDMAhgBsAznWqQWAJRB5iwlNzUaQaHmJHgUUUzAQtxa7CewIT64XdvZw0JDEgoWAJ2u37fz1tKjB4JQB3IK0eR2CDFii4mJ0nbGFIoOcsvF4oX1SQdNjdXl4DPThEwrKeMmFa-IBzQsJ%20VpD8qzwbQWE4hCEikzB3KFhvJN17EuEEQjFqgeIHXUIUPMy4xoGtfIBJTm1%20Ki4eQYzxpAsk3ouj86GlPx6TNqpXvtMw%20CXe97U5U47S2aw2rRBBWYkDyjWheWwuW%20vxa8IoYBGYTy80MWyBALiAKUViEPBOQXJvVGHgmBVJfDaIHp5NC4RYLWZjOZukWUTOIiozNE1U5eU%20vEZW16ErF0rAGRYsnAWKKSLRNkMECkcjoKmVMPi%20ry%20jMRg8Znc1TRKXVaHyfjRCAxRr4QNZvwAJiB6q66kNinoQB66FIAK7SAAuLC9Ppm3qGjRMwbDkfZ8bme1jT3yqh9AZ9KUM7WduMtUR9cJVjSUAA9vWBjUMsY3iHxjCAAPIABwjAEsAPYAOxkAB1ZL3B13QxGx12fP2I3QAMZ9ocsOsYFAQbC9PCQcg7pB5Z0ACV7TQAFmPx8HrxFexGlxf12owhReA48OQELwj%202AEQACI%20JIE5jv2XZ0IOdA%20P%20L7MCgR6UOAO6uL%20aHtgAojWkgALZdtIdDgRGF4wWOwYAG69kuRGyB6Pi9lRg5NNeeG0dIE66kAA):

I realize this is quite a few discrete components to have to duplicate 10 times. You might be able to find a *level shifter* with open drain capability. That would provide the same effect all in one package, if such a thing exists.

Comment: I linked the words "this applet" to the hyperlink using the hyperlink tool in the answer tool bar. You should learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For 100 mA you do not need a Darlington pair. A single MOSFET (or even BJT) with open drain (or open collector) will suffice.

As for the indicator LED, it will require a couple of mA of current, something that the MCU can easily source or sink, with current left over for a BJT base, if you use one.

Here's are designs for a single channel, which you repeat 9 more times:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOBB1P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left I use a MOSFET, with \$V_{GS(TH)} < 4V\$. The short spike of gate current is limited to 10 mA maximum, by R2.

On the right I employ a BJT, with current gain \$\beta\$ (\$h_{fe}\$) *at least* 70, to guarantee  maximum collector current of 100 mA. Base current is set to about 2 mA by R4.

R1/R3 is chosen to pass 2 mA through a *red* LED, but can be changed for whatever current you need there, and *should* be changed to suit the colour of LED you will be using.

Due to the open drain/collector you can connect a load between OUT and *any* positive supply (not exceeding \$V_{DS(MAX)}\$ or \$V_{CE(MAX)}\$ of the transistor). 12 V is fine, up to 30 V is probably OK too. Here I use a 12 V supply to operate a 12 V relay coil, for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNBX2j.png)</sup>